# Iterate records in rails view and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can i output categories and subcategories in rails view? Like this:

- First category name

  - **First** category child 1 name
  - **First** category child 2 name
  - **First** category child 3 name
- Second category name

  - **Second** category child 1 name
  - **Second** category child 2 name
  - **Second** category child 3 name

my **schema.rb**:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "title"
    t.boolean  "state",          default: true
    t.integer  "parent_id"       # id of parent category
end
```

my **categories_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    #child categories of current parent category
    @child_categories = Category.where(parent_id: @category.id)
    #subchild categories of current parent category
    @child_categories.each do |category|
        @subchild_categories = Category.where(parent_id: category.id)
    end
end
```

my **show.html.erb**

```
<% if @child_categories.any?  %>
<ul>
<% @child_categories.each do |child| %>
    <li>
        <%= child.title %>
        <ul>
            <% @subchild_categories.each do |subchild| %>
                <li><%= subchild.title %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Now i get something like this:

- First category name

  - **Second** category child 1 name
  - **Second** category child 2 name
  - **Second** category child 3 name
- Second category name

  - **Second** category child 1 name
  - **Second** category child 2 name
  - **Second** category child 3 name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#try this:    

def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    @child_categories = Category.where(parent_id: @category.id)

   @subchild_categories = {}
   @child_categories.each do |category|
     @subchild_categories[category.title] = Category.where(parent_id: category.id)
   end
end



#and in view:

<% @child_categories.each do |child| %>
   <li>
      <%= child.title %>
      <ul>
          <% @subchild_categories[child.title].each do |subchild| %>
              <li><%= subchild.title %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `children` method in your `Category` model that calls `where(parent_id: id)` and then you just use it

```
def self.children
  where(parent_id: id)
end
```

And then you can use it on you view as much as you want to:

```
@category.children.each do |child_category|
  child_category.children.each do |sub_child_category|
    sub_child_category.children.each do |sub_sub_child_category|
      // as much as you want to
    end
  end
end
```